# Is it fair enough to make model evaluation based on just "train_test_split"?

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation, train-test-split

I'm absolutely confused about model evaluation, interpreting its results and using `cross_val_score`. I don't understand why evaluation on a test set is usually considered as a final and solid result, while if we just choose other split, we'll get a different value which could be far worse (or far better) than the previous one. Below, I'll illustrate what I'm talking about with an example and after that I'll ask some more precise questions.

*I used a dataset from [Jason Brownlee](https://github.com/jbrownlee): https://github.com/jbrownlee/Datasets/blob/master/pima-indians-diabetes.data.csv

```
url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jbrownlee/Datasets/master/pima-indians-diabetes.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(url, names=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'Target'], header=None)
X, y = df.drop('Target', axis=1), df['Target']
```

Here is our target distribution:

[image: Target distribution]

```
X_rest, X_test, y_rest, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, 
                                                  random_state=777, stratify=y)
X_train, X_val, y_train, y_val = train_test_split(X_rest, y_rest, test_size=0.25, 
                                                  random_state=777, stratify=y_rest)
```

Checking sample's sizes:

```
Train size: 52.3 %
Val size:   17.6 %
Test size:  30.1 %
```

Tuning the hyper-parameters:

```
base_model = LogisticRegression(random_state=777, max_iter=2000)

params = {
    'C': np.arange(0, 5, 0.1)
}

grdSrch = GridSearchCV(base_model, params, scoring='average_precision', cv=5)
grdSrch.fit(X_val, y_val)
print(f'Best params: {grd.best_params_}')
```

Best params: {'C': 2.5}

Training model with the best parameter and getting an `average_precision_score` value:

```
model = LogisticRegression(C=grdSrch.best_params_['C'], random_state=777, max_iter=2000)
model.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred_scores = model.predict_proba(X_test)[:, 1]
print(f'Avg. precision: {average_precision_score(y_test, y_pred_scores)}')
```

**Avg. precision: 0.7067839537770597**

Now, I want to be sure that result is not unfair because of some unexpectedly good train/test splitting. And I use `cross_val_score` for that purpose:

```
res_ = cross_val_score(LogisticRegression(C=grd.best_params_['C'], random_state=777, max_iter=2000), 
                       X,
                       y,
                       scoring='average_precision',
                       cv=StratifiedKFold(n_splits=15, shuffle=True))

print(res_)
print()
print(f'Mean score: {np.round(res_.mean(), 4)}')
```

Then I get:

```
[0.7779402  0.69200873 0.63972188 0.82368544 0.6044146  0.70668374
 0.85022563 0.79848536 0.60740097 0.68802039 0.92567494 0.84554528
 0.61855088 0.78731357 0.79852637]

Mean score: 0.7443
```

And what do we see here? We got a pretty high variance among those results plus higher overall mean value. So, at this point I totally lost it. My questions are:

1. Can we use `cross_val_score` on a whole dataset to assess a fairness (?) of our final evaluation result?

   - If we can, why do we even use `train_test_split` with just one score when the `cross_val_score` gives us more clear picture about actual scores?
   - If we cannot, then for what reason?
2. It seems like we actually don't have any "final" result for any metric, because we can always get some pool of various scores depending on a train/test splitting. So, how can we make a real business decisions in such circumstances?

Answer (score 0):

Depend on data set but most preferred method because it gives your model the opportunity to train on multiple train-test splits. This gives you a better indication of how well your model will perform on unseen data.suppose ,you take 10-fold cross validation, the dataset would be split into 10 groups, and the model would be trained and tested 10 separate times so each group would get a chance to be the test set but in train test split ,there is one time .
Train test split method is good to use when you have a very large dataset and you are starting to build an initial model in your data science project. Keep in mind that because cross-validation uses multiple train-test splits, it takes more computational power and time to run than using the holdout method.

Comment: Thank you, I know that cross-validation takes more resources but that does not change the situation where our "final" score/prediction hugely depends on how train_test_split splits the whole dataset. My point is if we are lucky enough at splitting, then we get one result, but if we accidentally aren't, we can get an absolutely different one. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Yeah ,if you have time crunch and deploy your project then you should apply train test split .cross_val_score and train_test_split score kind of little bit difference value score cause  cross-validation apply multiple times train_test_split in whole dataset and takes time calculation.

Comment: If we get different value scores using `train_test_split` and `.cross_val_score().mean()`, which one we should choose as a base result to continue improve our model? And my second question is: which score should be chosen for making business decisions and why is it exactly?

Comment: Suppose if train test split score 74.5 and cross val score 72 then you can apply train test split  .If there is huge diffrence ,it means that your dataset not well preprocessing,cleasing and feature engineering.means that presence outlier ,missing value etc you know what i mean.By the way in industries mostly preferred train teat split for decision making and cross val score for check how your model is fit .

Comment: Thank you for making things much clearer. But I have one more question.
Let's say we got 74.5 with `train_test_split`, and 72 with `cross_val_score().mean()`, and it looks like our model fits well because the difference is small, but what if among those cross-validation scores there are several too different scores? For example, `[72, 69, 30, 73, 74, 98, 74, 86]` -- the avg. value is 72, but we also have 30, 98 and 86.
I mean, what is more important about model fitting evaluation: a diff. between `train_test_split` and `cross_val_score().mean()` or a variation among cross-validation scores?

Comment: Lots of technique ,first of all check skewness and distribution  before apply in cross_validation .if well distributed or skewness then go forward otherwise when you predict model higher chances that independent features and dependent feature are not well correlation and for prediction model should be perfectly correlated.

Comment: Thank you so much. So, if I understand you correctly, outliers among cross-validation scores say us that something goes wrong and we should investigate the reasons for that. And in this case, we also should ignore, that the mean CV-score is close to `train_test_split` score.

Comment: And one last question. The general workflow should be like: 
a dataset exploration, preprocessing, feature engineering -> splitting the dataset for train/val/test -> tuning the hyper-params -> CV for some random sample and checking scores -> if we got outliers, then return to the dataset exploration; otherwise go to creating a model -> fitting the model with train sample -> getting predictions/scores with test sample -> evaluating result using some metric(-s). Am I right?